# How to send multiple json response in php back to ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn =new mysqli("localhost","root","","registration");
$userid=isset($_POST['userid'])?$_POST['userid']:'';

//$re['success']=false;
$sql="call regtask2('$userid')";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$array = array();
if($res) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $array[]=$row ;
        $re['success']=true;
        $re['userObj']['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    }
}


else {
    $re['success']=false;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $sem=isset($_POST['sem'])?$_POST['sem']:'';
    $fname=isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:'';
    $year=isset($_POST['date'])?$_POST['date']:'';
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from studentdetails inner join studentmarks on studentdetails.studentid=studentmarks.studentid where firstname='$fname' and sem='$sem'");
    $re = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        print_r($row);
        //$options['userObj'][]=$row;
    }
}

echo json_encode ($re);
return;
?>
```

This is my full PHP code in this I need two json responses, 
1> when I refresh the page

```
$sql="call regtask2('$userid')";
```

This query has to work and pass the response to the ajax, then I am using click button. When I use click button this query has to work and pass the response

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from studentdetails inner join studentmarks on studentdetails.studentid=studentmarks.studentid where firstname='$fname' and sem='$sem'");
```

I this is poosible?

Comment: It is unclear what result you expect. Can you provide an example of the JSON which you expect as a result of your query?

Also, what exactly do you mean by _multiple json response_?

Comment: I am using two ajax which is using same php  and i am expecting two response differently

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just add second query result to your previous json !, also consider adding some validation into user input to prevent sql injection
getting userid from $_POST is really bad idea

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn =new mysqli("localhost","root","","registration");
$userid=isset($_POST['userid'])?$_POST['userid']:'';

//$re['success']=false;
$sql="call regtask2('$userid')";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$array = array();
$re = array();
if($res) {
    $re['success']=true;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $array[]=$row ;
        $re['userObj']['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    }
}


else {
    $re['success']=false;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $sem=isset($_POST['sem'])?$_POST['sem']:'';
    $fname=isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:'';
    $year=isset($_POST['date'])?$_POST['date']:'';
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from studentdetails inner join studentmarks on studentdetails.studentid=studentmarks.studentid where firstname='$fname' and sem='$sem'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $re['userObj'][]=$row;
        //$options['userObj'][]=$row;
    }
}

echo json_encode ($re);
return;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. Just split your php code. On refresh, load `script1.php` and for your other ajax call, load `script2.php`.
2. You will need to set identifiers for your calls. In your ajax, add an "is_submit=true" to the query. In your php, check that value.
3. Assign your return value to $return and return that.